# Data Segment starting at location 0

Tags: c, operating-system

**Interview Question :** For this hypothetical situation : If data segment of program started from address 0. What would happen?
Consider any Linux OS for this question. I understand the [basics of memory layout of a program](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/03/linux-processes-memory-layout/) but cannot figure out the exact answer to this question. Please list out the possibilities.

Comment: Then there would be no way of catching `NULL` dereferences (with `NULL` defined as `0`). Otherwise I believe it would work fine (assuming correctness of the program).

Comment: @WilliamAndrewMontgomery: Technically, it doesn't matter if `NULL` is defined as 0 because a *null pointer* can still have an address other than 0 even if `#define NULL 0`.  There are historical systems where this is the case, although it is uncommon.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Do you have an example of such a system?

Comment: @WilliamAndrewMontgomery: http://c-faq.com/null/machexamp.html

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the data segment starts at address 0.

```
int my_global;

void increment(int *ptr)
{
    assert(ptr != NULL);
    *ptr += 1;
}

void main()
{
    increment(&my_global);
}
```

So, what happens if `my_global` has address zero, and the null pointer *also* has address zero?

(Technically, this would not conform to the C standard, since the C standard mandates that addresses of global variables are *not* equal to `NULL`.)